# Как заставить функцию foreach() или while() работать корректно?

Tags: while, php, foreach

```
<php
$arr=array('test1'=>array('ww'=>array(0,0,0,0),'wq'=>array(1,0,0,0),'qe'=>array(0,0,0,0),'wq'=>array(20,0,0,0)), 'test2'=>array('re'=>array(25480,0,0,0),'ee'=>array(0,0,0,0)));
        foreach ($schet['test1'] as &$n) {
            $s[0]=$n[0]+$s[0];
            $s[1]=$n[1]+$s[1];
            $s[2]=$n[2]+$s[2];
            $s[3]=$n[3]+$s[3];
        }
        unset ($n);
    ?>

        <table width="400" border="3" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1">
          <tr>  
            <th scope="col">Баланс</th>
            <th scope="col"><? echo "$s[0]" ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><? echo "$s[1]" ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><? echo "$s[2]" ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><? echo "$s[3]" ?></th>
          </tr>
          <?php #delaem avto stroki tablici
          while (list ($key, $val)=each($arr['test1'])) { ?>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><? echo $key ?></th>
                <td><? echo "$val[0]" ?></td>
                <td><? echo "$val[1]" ?></td>
                <td><? echo "$val[2]" ?></td>
                <td><? echo "$val[3]" ?></td>
          </tr>
          <? } ?>
        </table>
```

Вот сокращенный код. Но он не работает. Первый массив функция `foreach()` обрабатывает как надо. Но уже следующая функция `while()` отказывается работать с этим же массивом. Как решить задачу?

Comment: - Эммм, первый цикл у вас собирает какую-то сумму, но запомнит её только на последний итерации. 
- Зачем unset($n)?
- Зачем тут костыли с while, list, each? замените всё на foreach ($schet['test1'] as $key=>val) и всё будет хорошо.
- <? echo "$val[0]" ?> замените на <? echo $val[0] ?> и кавычки там не нужны. Тоже самое касается вывода $s[3]

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо, теперь работает. Видать while() тупит в паре с foreach().
ПС: апострофы мне нужны, так как я для удобства здесь убрал лишнюю информацию.

Comment: Это не апострофы, а кавычки. Переменные в строках лучше клеить друг к другу, а не выводить в строке. `$str = "Пример, как надо клеить " . $var[0] . "переменные";`

Comment: @ua6xh, хм, как-то не задумывался над этим. Но на будущее буду делать только так. Выходит даже очень удобно

Comment: многострочный вывод можно реализовать вот так:
`<?php #delaem avto stroki tablici
          while (list ($key, $val)=each($schet['test1'])) { 
echo <<<END
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">$key</th>
                <td>$val[0]</td>
                <td>$val[1]</td>
                <td>$val[2]</td>
                <td>$val[3]</td>
          </tr>
END;
           } ?>
`
чуток код сократится и читабельность, ИМХО, повыше.

Comment: @demol0cv, лучше всего в шаблонах читается альтернативный синтаксис. Heredoc предназначен не для этого.

Comment: @demol0cv, спасибо. Точно такой код действительно лучше читать.